# Converting cartesian to polar integral

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

I feel like I almost have a grasp on regions of integration. I am a bit frustrated that I haven't fully gotten it, but I feel like I'm almost there. In this particular homework problem I have a Cartesian integral that I need to convert into a polar integral.

> Using polar coordinates, evaluate the integral $$\iint_{R} \sin(x^2 + y^2)\,dA$$ where $R$ is the region $1 \le x^2 + y^2 \le 81$.

In order to convert these to polar coordinates, I substituted $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$
(taking the long way)

\begin{align}
x^2+y^2&=(r\sin(\theta))^2(r\cos(\theta))^2 \\
&=r^2(\sin^2(\theta)+\cos^2(\theta))\\
&=r^2(1) = r^2
\end{align}

So I assumed the conversion would be straight-forward

$$\int{}\int_{1}^{9}\sin(r^2)\,r\,dr\,d\theta$$

The inner integral is easy enough to integrate, it only requires a single u-substitution, but I don't know what my range for $\theta$ is supposed to be.

I don't need the answer, but if someone could explain what I need to do I would be appreciative. I'd be willing to even answer the question myself if I were told *how* I was supposed to do so.

Comment: You have not any restriction on $\theta$; so, $0\le 0\le2\pi$.

Comment: So, I'm literally already there and there's nothing I need to worry about? I don't get why I'm over thinking some of these. Thank you.

Comment: Just draw these region

Comment: Because the region, which is an annulus, and the function both have radial symmetry, we can think of this as just integrating the radial function $ \ \sin (r^2) \ $ over a set of concentric infinitesimal annuli of "thickness" $ \ dr \ $ ; thus, $ \ \int_1^9 \ \  \sin (r^2) \ \cdot \ 2 \pi \ r \ \ dr \ $ .  Expressing this as a double integral, this becomes $ \ \int_0^{2 \pi} \ d\theta \ \int_1^9 \  \sin (r^2) \ \cdot \  \ r \ \ dr \ $ .  As you found in your set-up, the double integral is "separable" and the angular integration can be conducted separately.

Comment: I was able to come up with the correct answer once I knew the correct domain for $\theta$. I'll post my solution in a few minutes (more or less)

Comment: This has to be one of the loosest interpretations of "more or less" I've ever seen. Glad you figured it out, though!